# Return an output parameter value on database backup query result

Tags: sql-server, output, database-backups

I've created a procedure for creating a database backup. I want to return an output parameter for successful backup or in the condition of some error. But I do not know how to catch such messages from the message panel.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [DBO].[P_DB_BACKUP]
    (@v_result int = 0 output)
AS
    DECLARE @today_date VARCHAR(10) = convert(VARCHAR(10), getdate(), 120);
    DECLARE @sqlCommand VARCHAR(1000)
BEGIN
    SET @sqlCommand = 'backup database TEMP to disk =''D:TEMP_BCK_'+@today_date+'.BAK'' ';

    EXEC (@sqlCommand);
END;
```

When I run the procedure, I get the messages

> Processed 608 pages for database 'TEMP', file 'TEMP' on file 1.
>   Processed 2 pages for database 'TEMP', file 'TEMP_log' on file 1.
>   BACKUP DATABASE successfully processed 610 pages in 0.458 seconds (10.405 MB/sec).

My question is on this message I should be able to return 1 for the output parameter `@v_result` and -1 in case of any error. Is there any other way of doing this? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Try-Catch in your stored procedure like this -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [DBO].[P_DB_BACKUP]
(
    @v_result int = 0 output
)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @today_date VARCHAR(10) = convert(VARCHAR(10), getdate(), 120);
    DECLARE @sqlCommand VARCHAR(1000)

    BEGIN TRY

        SET @sqlCommand = 'backup database TEMP to disk =''D:TEMP_BCK_'+@today_date+'.BAK'' ';
        EXEC (@sqlCommand);
        SET @v_result = 1;

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH

        SET @v_result = -1;
        RAISERROR('YOUR ERROR MESSAGE', 16, 1);

    END CATCH

END
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a simple variable to your existing construction that stores the return value of the backup statement.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [DBO].[P_DB_BACKUP]
    (@v_result int = 0 output)
AS
    DECLARE @today_date VARCHAR(10) = convert(VARCHAR(10), getdate(), 120);
    DECLARE @sqlCommand VARCHAR(1000)
    DECLARE @iSQLStmtRet      AS    INT             = 0 -- <== new!!
BEGIN
    SET @sqlCommand = 'backup database TEMP to disk =''D:TEMP_BCK_'+@today_date+'.BAK'' ';

    EXEC @iSQLStmtRet = sp_executesql @sqlCommand; -- <== modified

END;
```

Depending on the return value of `@iSQLStmtRet` variable you can then PRINT out various information.

**Example:**

```
IF @iSQLStmtRet != 0
    BEGIN
        PRINT '-------------------------------------------------'
        PRINT ' Error during backup of ' + @nvDB2Backup + '!'
        PRINT ' Errocode: ' + cast(@iSQLStmtRet as nvarchar(20))
        PRINT '-------------------------------------------------'
    END
```